# gVim menus disappear in upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 16.04

Tags: gvim

GVim menus have disappear after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 (from 16.04).
F10 shows a menu but I don't know how to change the font size.

GVim is my code editor. It is VIM version 8, and shows as "installed" in the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the variable `guioptions`. `m` stands for the menu, `T` for the toolbar.

To add menu, set the options in ViM normal mode like:

```
:set guioptions+=m
```

To add toolbar

```
:set guioptions+=T
```

With `set guioptions?` ViM shows you the current settings.

If you want to have it permanently add this two lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set guioptions+=m
set guioptions+=T
```

see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hide_toolbar_or_menus_to_see_more_text.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be pedantic but isn't installing an older version of Ubuntu a "downgrade?"

And I'm not too familiar with gVim to offer any advice. I use Nano (command line) and Geany (desktop).

Steve Wright